# why for loop is used to generate numbers through function?

Tags: python-3.x

I can't get why `for i in gen(100): print(i)` is being used here. when i replace `print(i)` with `print(gen(i))` it start giving memory location. I do know that yield is used for one time storage but how exactly is it working?

```
    def gen(num):
        i = 0
        while i<num:
            x=i
            i+=1
            if x%7 == 0:
                yield x
    for i in gen(100):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield` is not used for one-time storage. `yield` makes a function return a generator

A generator is an iterable object (which means you can use it in place of any sequences such as `list(gen())`, `for i in gen()`, etc.). You can also pass it to the `next()` built-in function that advances a generator one step forward (makes it begin or start where it left off and run to the first `yield` it hits). It also returns the yielded value

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

print(list(gen()))  # prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(next(gen()))  # prints 0

gn = gen()
print(next(gn))     # prints 0
print(list(gn))     # prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(next(gn))     # raises StopIteration, because the generator is 
                    #  exhausted (the generator function ran to completion)
```

The reason why you're getting a memory address from `print(gen(i))` is because you're actually printing a generator object, not the value it produces. So that's why generators first have to be iterated somehow